# pass data to view controller in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

im trying to pass data from a view controller to another viewController that is contained in a tab bar controller. My segue is wired up from the first view controller to the tab bar controller (the container). Whenever the segue is performed, it doesn't actually pass the data to the next view controller. However, when I wire up the segue directly from the first view controller to the next view controller it successfully passes the data. The problem with this though is that it doesnt show the tabs. My questions is, how can i pass data to the viewcontroller of the tab bar controller AND still show the tabs at the bottom?? Im using the prepareForSegue method and initializing the nextViewController not the tab bar controller. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You need to post the code for what you tried in prepareForSegue to pass the data when you segued to the tab bar controller. Also, which controller in the tab bar controller are you trying to pass the data to (in which tab)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSuserDefaults to store data and then use that in any controller.

Comment: I was able to get this to work but have a question for you. Would using this not be a good idea to get a users profile picture from facebook? Because since it saves in the app, if a user logged out then back in would it change it to the new picture or keep the old one?

Comment: When user logs in back, delete the old session details and save new session details again. That's how it works

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to pass data from one view controller to another view controller in UITabBarController, you better save the changes from one view controller and get the values from another view controller, using any of the storage options available. This way you keep view controllers independent of each other and neat code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach, set delegate for tabbarcontroller, in following delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

   if ([tabBarController selectedIndex] == seconviewcontrollerindex){

     NSArray *viewControllers = [tabBarController viewControllers];
     //This array contains all the viewcontrollers available in that tab bar controller
     //By getting viewcontroller of perticular index you can set values here

   }
}
```

Note: not sure if this is perfect approach, so please look for other answers too.